# Need 'built-in.o' error when compiling U-Boot

Tags: linux, build, kernel, u-boot

I am trying to compile U-Boot for the developer board with armv7 processor. It has a Rockchip RK3288 processor. The commands I use are:

- `make evb-rk3288_defconfig`
- `export CC=/opt/workspace/sdk/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-z86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-`

or

- `export CC=/opt/workspace/sdk/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

and then

- `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CC`

I get an error when I try this way. The error I get is as follows:

```
      .
      .
      .
      HOSTCC tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o
      HOSTCC tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o
      HOSTCC tools/lib/rsa/rsa-verify.o
      HOSTCC tools/lib/rsa/rsa-mod-exp.o
      HOSTCC tools/lib/aes/aes-encrypt.o
      HOSTCC tools/lib/aes/aes-decrypt.o
      HOSTCC tools/mkimage.o
      HOSTCC tools/fit_info.o
      HOSTCC tools/fit_check_sign.o
      HOSTCC tools/proftool
      HOSTCC tools/fdtgrep.o
      HOSTCC tools/spl_size_limit
      HOSTCC tools/lib/crc8.o
      HOSTLD tools/mkenvimage
      HOSTLD tools/dumpimage
      HOSTLD tools/fit_info
      HOSTLD tools/mkimage
      HOSTLD tools/fit_check_sign
      HOSTLD tools/gen_ethaddr_crc
      HOSTLD tools/fdtgrep
      AR arch/arm/cpu/built-in.o
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/cpu/armv7/cache_v7_asm.o', needed by 'arch/arm/cpu/armv7/built-in.o'. Durdu.
    make[1]: *** Bitmemiş işler için bekliyor....
      CC arch/arm/cpu/armv7/cache_v7.o
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/lib/vectors.o', needed by 'arch/arm/lib/built-in.o'. Durdu.
    make: *** [Makefile:1814: arch/arm/lib] Error 2
    make: *** Bitmemiş işler için bekliyor....
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/board.o
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/cpu-info.o
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/boot_mode.o
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/sdram.o
      CC board/rockchip/evb_rk3288/evb-rk3288.o
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/rk3288/clk_rk3288.o
      AR board/rockchip/evb_rk3288/built-in.o
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/rk3288/rk3288.o
      CC arch/arm/mach-rockchip/rk3288/syscon_rk3288.o
    make: *** [Makefile:1814: arch/arm/cpu/armv7] Error 2
      AR arch/arm/mach-rockchip/rk3288/built-in.o
      AR arch/arm/mach-rockchip/built-in.o
    root@pardus:/opt/workspace/uboot#
```

Comment: Don't `export ARCH=arm` as that's not required and can break things.  Where did you your sources?  Those errors imply cache_v7_asm.S and vector.S are missing.

Comment: I wasn't using `export ARCH=arm`, now I didn't type it while doing the make but I got the same error.

My resources: [main source](https://linux-readdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), [U-boot](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot), [linaro cross-compiler](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/), [arm cross-compiler](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads). As you said cache_v7_asm.S and vector.S are missing. But if I don't impliment them in the makefile, it gives the same error for other files.

Comment: To be clearer, `make ARCH=arm ...` is also wrong.  And given that the source file exists in github, something is wrong with your checkout if it is not present.

Comment: I guess there was a problem when using `git clone`. As you said, I downloaded properly and started compiling without using `make ARCH=arm`. This time, this error did not come, another error came, I will open a different topic for it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to incomplete or corrupted downloading of U-Boot files. It should download properly.

When compiling, the `make ARCH=arm` statement should be removed.