# "Missing external blobs" Error when compiling U-Boot Cross armhf

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, kernel, cross-compiling, u-boot

I am trying to compile U-Boot for the developer board with armv7 processor. It has a Rockchip RK3288 processor. The commands I use are:

- `make evb-rk3288_defconfig`
- `export CC=/opt/workspace/sdk/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-z86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-`

or

- `export CC=/opt/workspace/sdk/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

and then

- `make CROSS_COMPILE=$CC -j4`

I get an error when I try this way. The error I get is as follows:

```
  .
  .
  .
  CC      tpl/common/spl/spl.o
  AR      tpl/arch/arm/mach-rockchip/built-in.o
  CC      tpl/lib/display_options.o
  AR      spl/common/spl/built-in.o
  CC      spl/lib/display_options.o
  AR      tpl/common/spl/built-in.o
  AR      tpl/lib/built-in.o
  LD      tpl/u-boot-tpl
  OBJCOPY tpl/u-boot-tpl-nodtb.bin
  SYM     tpl/u-boot-tpl.sym
  COPY    tpl/u-boot-tpl.bin
  MKIMAGE tpl/u-boot-tpl-rockchip.bin
  AR      spl/lib/built-in.o
  LD      spl/u-boot-spl
  OBJCOPY spl/u-boot-spl-nodtb.bin
  SYM     spl/u-boot-spl.sym
  CAT     spl/u-boot-spl-dtb.bin
  COPY    spl/u-boot-spl.bin
  CAT     idbloader.img
  BINMAN  all
Image 'main-section' is missing external blobs and is non-functional: blob-ext

Some images are invalid
```

You can check the error that I asked and solved before this error, from this link: [previous resolved bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68828252/need-built-in-o-error-when-compiling-u-boot/68919252#68919252)

Resources I used: [Main Resources](https://linux-readdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), [U-Boot](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot), [Linaro Cross-Compiler](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/), [Arm Cross-Compiler](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move forward to a newer U-Boot in order to acquire this patch or one of the related Rockchip patches dealing with ROM files described in the thread:  [[PATCH v4 06/27] rockchip: Enable building a SPI ROM image on jerry](https://www.mail-archive.com/u-boot@lists.denx.de/msg377655.html)  Your reported U-Boot version is ca. 2019, patches are ca. 2020.

Comment: As you said I changed the U boot version and switched to: [link](https://source.denx.de/u-boot/custodians/u-boot-rockchip). When I use `make menuconfig`, I see 2021.10-rc1 as version. But I don't understand how to use that patch you mentioned. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I examined the article in the link you gave and opened the files specified there one by one and looked at the relevant code blocks. The files I have already have the same code blocks/lines. But the error persists.

Comment: I haven't gone through the error here yet, but still, since the image files are created, I put them on the sd card and put them on my board and restart. It sees the SD Card, but the version seems low and gives an error. Error output when I reboot: [error output](https://pastebin.com/gpiCq3UD)